# Given a list of Partition Keys, look up matching records in Table Storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm currently using the following for every key that I need to query:

```
TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, itemId)
```

However this is unwieldy at the scale of thousands or tens of thousands.

Is there any way to pass a list of `itemIds` so that I'm in/out one time?

I've tried this but the `Contains` is not supported:

```
   IQueryable<Item> queryForItems = this.itemTable.CreateQuery<Item>().Where(s => itemIds.Contains(s.PartitionKey));
```

Thoughts?

Comment: To clarify - are you looking to get a single item back?  If not, there is support for paging; conversely if your `RowKey` is intrinsically sortable, you can query on a range of row keys.

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported out of the box. What you can try to do is to generate a list of equals filters and then combine them with OR condition.

Something like this:

```
var partitions= new []{"partition1", "partition2", "partition3"};
var filters = partitions.Select(key => TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, key)).ToArray();
```

And then you can combine your filters using a loop:

```
string finalFilter = String.Empty
for (var i = 0; i < filters.Length; i++)
combine = TableQuery.CombineFilters(finalFilter, TableOperators.Or, filters[i]);
```

Comment: @BrendanGreen, looks like 15 is the max number https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/querying-tables-and-entities